# Checking RAM slots on Windows-10: Discrepancy between wmic and Crucial scanner

Tags: windows-10, memory

I am trying to find RAM configuration for my Ideapad 520s (80X200EPIN).

1. `wmic` shows 2 memory devices with capacity of 32GB:

```
C:\Users\joshi>wmic memphysical get MaxCapacity, MemoryDevices
MaxCapacity  MemoryDevices 33554432     2
```

2. `Task manager` shows `Slots used: 1 of 2`:

[image: Attached screenshot]

3. However, system check from `Crucial` only 1 slot with 16GB max capacity.

Can someone please let me know which one is true, and why the discrepancy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The
[Lenovo ideapad 520 Hardware Maintenance Manual](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/ideapad520-15ikb_520x-15ikb_hmm_201705.pdf)
only shows one replaceable DIMM slot.

From this I gather that the other slot is not replaceable,
and it also takes some extended manipulations to even get to the one that
is replaceable:

---

[image]

---

Comment: True, I followed the steps to see that there is indeed only 1 slot. Not sure why Windows 10 tools were misleading :-(